# How to limit the number of concurrent connections?

Tags: socket.io

If I run a nodejs server with express and socket.io, how can I limit the number of concurrent connections to an arbitrary number ? ie: during handshake, check if limit was reached or not, and if so, refuse connection ?

Answer (score 0):

In your `connection` event handler, you can check the value of:

```
io.sockets.clients().length
```

And decide what to do based on it. If you only want connected clients:

```
io.sockets.clients().filter(function(s) {return !s.disconnected;}).length
```